# What are the more efficient, or easier, methods of handling electromagnetic interactions?

Tags: molecular-modeling, molecular-interactions, electric-field, atomistic-simulation, magnetic-field

Since metals, metalloids, non-metals, and composites, have differing characteristics, plug-and-play methods, so to speak, would be useful.

Also, as it’s well known that a moving electrical field generates a magnetic field, and vice-versa, finding ways to reduce that complexity while retaining a reasonable level of correctness would be highly useful.

Comment: +1 and welcome to the site, but what exactly do you wish to calculate? You want to "handle" electromagnetic interactions when doing what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify long range interaction by reducing precision with range. Useful algorithm for it is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation

It is usually used for gravity, but it can be applied for other forces too. With it you can do something better than just to ignore long range interaction, as is usually done, especially important with magnetic fields at larger scale.